# Weird HTML Table row height when table is overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

**Case 1 Before Overflow :** Normal and Acceptable. http://jsfiddle.net/mg8869ou/1/

**Case 2 After Overflow :** Problematic after adding cells Only To Right-Side. Making "Unnecessary" height for whole row and also whole `<table>`. http://jsfiddle.net/w1dc380w/4/

Any single solution for my all tables having multiple cells lengthy text?

Comment: Is your problem that the table tries to make itself as narrow as possible? I'm not sure there is a solution to that, other than giving it an explicit width in pixels (or ems). Or maybe you could do something with `table-layout:fixed`. Hey, how about giving every cell `white-space:nowrap`.

Comment: Is my problem not clear above?

Comment: No, not unless you'd be satisfied with giving every cell `white-space:nowrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this jquery:

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].rows[i]; i++) {
    if (row.offsetHeight > 200) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].style.width = "1500px";
        if (row.offsetHeight > 200) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].style.width = "2000px";
            if (row.offsetHeight > 200) {
                document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].style.width = "2500px";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When there are no absolute widths designated to the columns or to the total table, it is assumed that it should be no wider than the page. Your solution is to either give each column a specified width (e.g. `min-width:100px` - [see JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lwbz4a0/)), or to place a wrapper around your table with `overflow:scroll` and then giving the table a width such that each column is the right size ([see JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84Lw1b77/)).

---

**Edit** As suggested by [Mr Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister) you could also give each `td` the `whitespace:nowrap` property. This will make sure each `td` will stretch as much as is necessary to display its contents on one line. This not not recommended when using longer texts though.

Comment: but i need single solution for my all tables (many), my all tables have totally different text, number of rows and columns etc. none of your suggestions will work.

Comment: @feacco And then the only problem with the `whitespace:nowrap` method would be that it isn't good for longer texts. Am I right there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but min-width will not work for all my tables because all have different length data, same in width  all tables have different no. of cells and length, so please remove your answer so it will go to unanswered, thanks to understand.

Comment: @feacco Could you then at least better describe what you want? Currently my solutions solve your question as it is given, so a better answer can only be given if you specify more exactly.

Comment: combination of two things can solve this: use of whitespace:nowrap to remove white-space or make every cell single line + force longest cell of every row and column to be square or nearly square will make table compact.

Comment: i think it can be done with javascript, to get the longest cell of every row and column and make those square by making width and height always same. how to do this or any better idea?